# VBA to replace value in all XMLs in a folder with ones in a column in Excel

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I've researched this and decided I need a bit of help with my VBA code. I wonder if anyone can help.

I have many XMLs in a folder, I would like to change all the values which sit next to the key *Company* and replace them with the words that I have inputted in a list in column A in Excel. So the `first.xml` in the folder I want to change the value of which sits under the *Company* field to the word that's in Cell *A1*, the second xml to change the value to the word that's in Cell *A2*, etc.

I've done the code below, up this only works with a specific file, I tried modifying it to do all files in the xml, but seem to only be able to update the 
first xml, with the last field in column A.

```vb
Sub XMLTest()
    Dim myVar As String, pathToXML As String
    Dim xmlDoc As Object, xmlRoot As Object

    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    pathToXML = "H:\Macro Stuff\xmls\Number1.xml" '<--- change the path

    Call xmlDoc.Load(pathToXML)
    Set xmlRoot = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Product").Item(0)

    myVar = .Cells(1, 1).Value '<--- your value
    xmlRoot.SelectSingleNode("Company").Text = myVar
    Call xmlDoc.Save(pathToXML)
End Sub
```

With some testing I managed to compile the code below, but again it doesn't work needed, and wondered if any of you experts could lend a helping hand to the code.

```vb
Sub XMLTestTEST()
    Dim myVar As String, pathToXML As String
    Dim xmlDoc As Object, xmlRoot As Object

    Const sSearchString As String = "C:\Macro Stuff\xmls\*.xml"
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim sFilePath As String
    sFileName = Dir(sSearchString)

    Do While sFileName <> ""
        sFilePath = "C:\Macro Stuff\xmls\" & sFileName  'Get full path to file
    Loop

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lLastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

        For lRow = 1 To lLastRow

            Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
            'pathToXML = "H:\Macro Stuff\xmls\Number1.xml" '<--- change the path
            Call xmlDoc.Load(sFilePath)
            Set xmlRoot = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Product").Item(0)
            myVar = .Cells(lRow, 1).Value '<--- your value
            xmlRoot.SelectSingleNode("Company").Text = myVar
            Call xmlDoc.Save(sFilePath)

        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Many thanks in advance, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ever heard about  in·den·ta·tion ? ( in-ˌden-ˈtā-shən \)
Try http://www.oaltd.co.uk/indenter/indentpage.asp

Comment: can you please show your xml?

Comment: @KarthickGunasekaran its

`<Product>
 <Name>Bottle 2</Name>
 <Company>Test 2</Company>
 <Cost>£100.00</Cost>
</Product>`

but also want to change
`<Products>
 <Product>
  <Name>Bottle 2</Name>
  <Company>Test 2</Company>
  <Cost>£100.00</Cost>
 </Product>
<Products>`